# "This operation requires an interactive window station" - Update/Driver install error

Tags: drivers, windows-10, updates

I have recently been getting errors when windows update tries to install/update drivers. Windows update simply says that there was an error while installing updates and asks to try again, to no avail. When I attempted to manually fix the issue by updating the driver within device manager, I received the error "This operation requires an interactive window station".

Originally the problem was for my bluetooth driver that I had uninstalled, and was trying to reinstall. This issue was fixed by reinstalling windows. Windows installed the driver during setup. However, now I am receiving the same error when I plug in my secondary monitor, and my Samsung Galaxy Tab 4.

Has anyone found a fix for this? I searched other forums as well and the closest solution I found was to create another user account with admin rights and that should work. I enabled my built-in admin account and tried, but that did not work. I also attempted to use the windows 10 update troubleshooter located here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-update-troubleshooter . This did not work either.

System:

```
Computer Type: Laptop 
System Manufacturer/Model Number: HP Envy 17 3200 
OS: Windows 10 Pro x64 
CPU: Intel Core i7-3820QM 2.70GHz 
Motherboard: InsydeH20 03.72.05F.0b 
Memory: 16384MB 
Graphics Card: AMD Radeon HD 7800M Series
```

Thanks!

Comment: share the file "C:\Windows\Inf\setupapi.dev.log" on OneDrive and post a share link here.

Comment: Same Problem here....